# Forgotten Disney movie from 80s or 90s about a popular boy who becomes magnetic

Tags: story-identification, movie

All I remember is this really popular boy becomes magnetic. Paper clips, watches, stuff like that just starts sticking to him. At the same time an unattractive girl has the same thing happen to her. At the end of the movie these two are pulled together by the magnetic power and they share an awful kiss in front of the whole school. Anyone know the name?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's an episode of the 1985 Steven Spielberg series "Amazing Stories" -- Season 1, Episode 2: "[The Main Attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing_Stories_(1985_TV_series)#Season_1_(1985%E2%80%9386))"

Comment: Full episode: https://youtu.be/MSZvg23jHZE The kiss is at 28:06